# how to get whole data of html table using curl or macro

Tags: php, html, excel, curl

I have tried this code but this gives me hyperlinks value only, but i want to extract all the data from table. My HTML table contains 1514 rows and 7 columns along with pagination its contains 125 number of pages to show. How can I get all data from the table and not just the hyperlinks?

```
  <?php
$ch=curl_init('https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);

    preg_match('#<table[^>]*>(.+?)</table>#is', $page, $matches);
    foreach ($matches as &$match) {
         $match = $match;

    }
    echo '<table>';
        echo $matches[0];
    echo '</table>';
    ?>
```

Comment: it will be a lot easier for You if You use library like simple_html_dom, or DOMDocument [link](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Comment: i want to get table data only not body text or paragraph. table contains many pages to display this data because data exists in large amount.

Comment: Sure, You have very nice manual there: [link](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: sorry @Daimos  i have worked on it. but this link doesn't helped me. i am unable to extract the data

Answer (score 0):

Like i said before, there is no problem if You use simple html dom:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html');
$tr = $html->find('table[id=example] tr');
foreach ($tr as $row)
{
    foreach ($row->find('td') as $td)
    {
        echo $td->plaintext.'<br/>';
    }
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

sory i just saw that Alex have edited answer too.

PS. blank page? Put error_reporting(E_ALL); on the begining, You will see errors

Comment: i have checked this. this give me empty page

Comment: download simple_html_dom library, include it (only simple_html_dom.php file), You got the link from my comments

Comment: i have include simple_html_dom library and put error_reporting(E_ALL); on the beginning but data is not shown on the page. still empty page is shown.

Comment: look for error reporting topic. maybe try "try{}catch{}". My code works fine, tested

Comment: yeah your code is working i  have done it. but this doesn't helped me alot because i want to logon in webpage and then fetch data.

Comment: this code does not worked when html table page maintain session.

Comment: so You have two problems: 1. login, using curl, 2. get table data. Connect with curl and use cookies if need session, then use this code